# SQL Server full-text search

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I want to use the full-text index to search word:

How can I use 'contain' or 'freetext' to get the same result as   `"like '%dd%' "`?
If I use `contain(table,'data')`, it only finds `"....the data is ...."`
How can I use `contain search 'dat'`  to find data?

Answer (score 5):

While LIKE is searching for character patterns within a string, SQL Server's full text search is word based. The index is built using [word breakers and stemmers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142509.aspx) to tokenize the text into words. So, you can search for whole words or perform [prefix searches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142492.aspx) (so that `CONTAINS (YourColumn, ' "dat*" ' )` would find the word data in your example), but you cannot replicate the behavior of `like '%dd%'` with full text.